# how can I listen to changes in code in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 2. I have a component with an input.
I want to be able to write some code when the input value changes.
The binding is working, and if the data is changed (from outside the component) I can see that there is change in the dom.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test'
})
@View({
    template: `
    <div>data.somevalue={{data.somevalue}}</div>`
})
export class MyComponent {

    _data: Data;
    @Input()
    set data(value: Data) {
        this.data = value;
    }
    get data() {
        return this._data;
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    dataChagedListener(param) {
        // listen to changes of _data object and do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the lifecycle hook `ngOnChanges`:

```
export class MyComponent {
  _data: Data;
  @Input()
  set data(value: Data) {
    this.data = value;
  }
  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges([propName: string]: SimpleChange) {
    // listen to changes of _data object and do something...
  }
}
```

This hook is triggered when:

> if any bindings have changed

See these links for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html

Comment: the problem is that the data object is not a primitive value. I want to know when the member "somevalue" of data changes.

Comment: In fact, Angular2 won't detect this through `ngOnChanges`. The latter is only notified when references change not the content... See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6458

Comment: Setting data will be detected (`this.data = ...`) but setting value on data properties won't (`this.data.someValue = ...`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments of [Thierry Templier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35680734/3000068), `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook can only detect changes to primitives. I found that by using [`ngDoCheck`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) instead, you are able to check the state of the object manually to determine if the object's members have changed:

[A full Plunker can be found here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cBTSDP9HUWVHx5RL8XM5). But here's the important part:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'listener',
    template: `
        <div style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
            <h3>Listener</h3>
            <p>{{primitive}}</p>
            <p>{{objectOne.foo}}</p>
            <p>{{objectTwo.foo.bar}}</p>

            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of log">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ListenerComponent {
    @Input() protected primitive;
    @Input() protected objectOne;
    @Input() protected objectTwo;

    protected currentPrimitive;
    protected currentObjectOne;
    protected currentObjectTwo;

    protected log = ['Started'];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCurrentObjectState();
    }

    getCurrentObjectState() {
        this.currentPrimitive = this.primitive;
        this.currentObjectOne = _.clone(this.objectOne);
        this.currentObjectTwoJSON = JSON.stringify(this.objectTwo);
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.log.push('OnChages Fired.')
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        this.log.push('DoCheck Fired.');

        if (!_.isEqual(this.currentPrimitive, this.primitive)){
            this.log.push('A change in Primitive\'s state has occurred:');
            this.log.push('Primitive\'s new value:' + this.primitive);
        }

        if(!_.isEqual(this.currentObjectOne, this.objectOne)){
            this.log.push('A change in objectOne\'s state has occurred:');
            this.log.push('objectOne.foo\'s new value:' + this.objectOne.foo);
        }

        if(this.currentObjectTwoJSON != JSON.stringify(this.objectTwo)){
            this.log.push('A change in objectTwo\'s state has occurred:');
            this.log.push('objectTwo.foo.bar\'s new value:' + this.objectTwo.foo.bar);
        }

        if(!_.isEqual(this.currentPrimitive, this.primitive) || !_.isEqual(this.currentObjectOne, this.objectOne) || this.currentObjectTwoJSON != JSON.stringify(this.objectTwo)) {
             this.getCurrentObjectState();
        }
    }
```

It should be noted that the Angular documentation provides this caution about using `ngDoCheck`:

> While the ngDoCheck hook can detect when the hero's name has changed,
>   it has a frightful cost. This hook is called with enormous frequency —
>   after every change detection cycle no matter where the change
>   occurred. It's called over twenty times in this example before the
>   user can do anything.
>
> Most of these initial checks are triggered by Angular's first
>   rendering of unrelated data elsewhere on the page. Mere mousing into
>   another input box triggers a call. Relatively few calls reveal actual
>   changes to pertinent data. Clearly our implementation must be very
>   lightweight or the user experience will suffer.

Comment: I don't like what I see. This can kill performance. Is there any other way to cacth any change on object?

Comment: @AngularOne Yep. Performance is something to be mindful of with this, as noted with the quote from the documentation. I'm not aware of a better way to handle it (but I'm still pretty new to Angular myself!)